# python script runs on its own through terminal but not when it's executed in Java with Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, python, eclipse

python script runs on its own through terminal but not when it's executed in Java with Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

here's my script.  i set my python interpreter in Eclipse the proper way and I don't know what to do.

```
#!/usr/bin python

import subprocess

def execute(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    print (proc_stdout)

execute("command 1", "commnand 2", ...)
```

Comment: can you also provide with the JAVA code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up fixing my Java process to a ProcessBuilder as you mentioned...thanks for that!  The only extra thing I had to tweak was the commands. It needed to be a String[] object where the first 2 strings are "/bin/bash", "-c"

```
String[] cmds = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "python scriptName.py" };
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can´t do much without seeing the java code (Most likely the problem is here).

I still can recommend you not to use "Runtime.getRuntime().exec()", use this instead (Might solve your problem):

```
String yourCommand = "Python ExampleScript.py";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(yourCommand);
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

**Edit:** If you are using complete paths, remember to use this:

(I had the same problem a couple weeks ago)

```
yourCommand.replaceAll("\\\\","/")
```

(I fixed a mistake in the code too)